# equation with canceled terms

Tags: equations

How to write this equation please

[image]

xs'e^x + xse^x + s^2e^{2x} − xse^x = e^{2x},

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Package `cancel` helps ;-) There might be other packages as well

Comment: Also, please edit your question title to something a little more meaningful.

Answer (score 10):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cancel}

\begin{document}

\[
xs'e^x + \cancel{xse^x} + s^2e^{2x} − \cancel{xse^x} = e^{2x},
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

When you load the `cancel` package as suggested by Christian, you do the following:

`xs'e^{x} + \cancel{cse^{x}} + s^2 e^{2x} - \cancel{xse^{x}} = e^{2x}`

Notice the `\cancel{}` command.