# How do I negate fractions and whole equations

Tags: katex

If I'm trying to negate `\frac{1}{4}` or just whole equations how do I do that?

I've tried searching through questions and there are just awnsers on how you do it with symbols like: \neq, \not (etc).

Comment: you question isn't very clear, do you want `$-\frac{1}{4}$` ?

Comment: Can you show us a sketch with neageted `\frac{1}{4}`?

Comment: negating in a simple fraqtion is basically like a backslash over a fraction or a equation like when simplifying 1/(x - 1) + 1/4 = 1 the first step is removing 1/4. on paper you just draw a line acros 1/4 (negating the fraqtion) and 1 - 1/4 on the other side. so how do i draw a backslash acros an equation/fraction?

Comment: see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/376932/equation-with-canceled-terms/376934?noredirect=1.

Comment: But I'm not sure that also works in KaTeX, which is off-topic for this site (the site is only about "full" TeX/LaTeX and derivatives, that have packages such as `cancel` to facilitate this kind of extended functionality).

Comment: I found the solution katex cant use the package cancel but it does have a function called /bcancel{content}

Answer (score 4):

I think you mean 'cancel' rather than 'negate', in which case one possible answer is to use the [cancel package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cancel).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cancel}
\begin{document}
\[\cancel{\frac{1}{4}}\]
\end{document}
```

[image: cancel]

Comment: I found the solution katex cant use the package cancel but it does have a function called /bcancel{content}