# Equation with canceled terms using an arrow

Tags: equations, arrows

I know this question is [already asked](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/376932/equation-with-canceled-terms). I wanted to use an arrow as the canceling arrow with a zero near the arrow head as follows.

[image]

Comment: Note that the `cancel` package has some drawbacks because of its use of the picture environment (which can only draw lines at certain slopes). See [this question and its answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/546693/125871) for more information and a solution using `tikz`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package [`cancel`](https://ctan.org/pkg/cancel) also provides a command `\cancelto{<value>}{<expression>}` that adds an arrow over `<expression>`, pointing to `<value>`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel}
\begin{document}
\[
\cancelto{0}{\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}} = \kappa \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial z^2} + v_z \frac{\partial T}{\partial z}
\]
\end{document}
```